# Magento 1 - How to set HTTP Response Code in Custom REST API

Tags: magento-1.9, module, api, rest-api, web-services

Hi Guys for a project i try to extend the Magento REST API.
I have some problems with my error handling. I don't know how to send the right Http Response Code. I tried it with something like this:

```
    $this->_errorMessage($e->getMessage(), Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, array(
         'item' => $data
    ));
    return;
```

I get the right message as a response but the status code is always 207.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure the whole HTTP response with the response object from a controller:

```
$this->getResponse()
    ->clearHeaders()
    ->setHeader('HTTP/1.0', YOUR_STATUS_CODE, true)
    ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html') // can be changed to json, xml...
    ->setBody(YOUR_RETURN_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using the following approach please suggest me If I am using the wrong approach?

Included following class in my custom namespace

```
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
```

Return 400(bad Request)

```
if(empty($data)){
        throw new InputException(__('Not a valid data'));
}
```

Return 404 (Not Found)

```
if(empty($data)){
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Not a valid data'));
}
```

Comment: This will send a stack trace to user which is not what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

`$this->_errorMessage()` is used by operations performing multi-create or multi-update to provide status of individual create/update operations. In this case HTTP status code is always set to multi-status (`207`).

If error is critical, use `$this->_critical($message, $code)`. 
If execution can be continued, use `$this->_error($message, $code)`.