# Return a 304 HTTP response from within a REST API method?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

In a custom REST API endpoint method, returning the object promised in the service class interface will generate a `200 OK` response. Additionally, I can return a specific HTTP error code by throwing an particular type of exception. For example, throwing a `NoSuchEntityException` returns a `404 NOT FOUND` and a `AuthorizationException` returns a `401 UNAUTHORIZED`.

My question: is there a way to return other HTTP codes, such as a `304 NOT MODIFIED` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom status codes are currently not supported, you can only get one of the following: 200, 400, 401, 403, 404, 406, 500 (see `\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception`). If you have real use case when you need this functionality, feel free to create pull request or file an issue at https://github.com/magento/magento2 .

Comment: Hi @Alex Paliarush,
Thanks for the answer. Just I want to know how we can send the above-mentioned error code from our custom rest api call(Post/Get)? Can you please show me the example?

Comment: Hi using this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83852/how-to-set-http-response-code-in-custom-rest-api/166468#166468

Answer (score 2):

You can try send a custom http code in your service class using `ResponseInterface`.

Here a little example:

1. Define your service interface like this:

```
<?php

namespace Test\Module\Api;

interface TestApiInterface
{
    /**
    * @api
    *
    * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
    */
    public function foo();
}
```

Now on your service class definition

```
<?php

namespace Paymentez\Module\Model;

use Test\Module\Api\TestApiInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\{
    RequestInterface,
    ResponseInterface
};

class TestApi implements TestApiInterface
{
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
    */
    protected $request;

    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
    */
    protected $response;

    /**
    * CustomerAddress constructor.
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
    */
    public function __construct(RequestInterface $request,
        ResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    /**
    * @api
    *
    * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
    */
    public function foo()
    {
        $rawContent = $this->request->getContent();
        $params = json_decode($rawContent, true);

        $response = $this->response;
        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $response->setContent(json_encode([
            'status' => false,
            'request_params' => $params
        ]));

        $response->send();

        // Ugly trick  for force this response
        die;
    }
}
```

Now you can see the use of `die` sentence, but this trick prevent the next override of http status code and headers on the finally response